# Closures. Why is "parent function's" lexical environment being removed in this case?

Tags: javascript, function, garbage-collection, closures

```
function f() { 
  let value = 123; 
  function g() { 
    alert(value); 
  } 
  return g; 
} 
let g = f(); // the lexical environment of parent function exists
g = null; // ... there's no lexical environment of parent function
```

On some sources I've read that after we gave to `g` variable value of `null`, the "parent function's" lexical environment is removed.
I don't get why. **We just cleared `g` variable - `g = null`.  The nested function remains in the code, no one deleted it.**

Doesn't a nested function always store a reference to the parent function just because the code of this nested function is inside its  "parent" function? I mean browser sees a function, then sees another nested function inside its function and thinks: *"Since there is another nested function inside this " parent" function, the parent function's lexical environment won't be deleted. Because nested function still contains the link to the lexical environment of its parent function."*

How does this happen? Why does reassigning a variable, containing a nested function, remove the lexical environment of the parent function `f()`?

Comment: When you reassign the variable, its old value becomes garbage and will be collected eventually.

Comment: "*function remains in the code*" - you need to distinguish between the function definition and the function object, as well as between the abstract scope and the concrete lexical environment.

Comment: What exactly is your understanding what "*lexical environment of its parent function*" refers to (and how many)?

Comment: @Bergi okay, I'll tell how I understand this. Firstly, `f` function (I call it "parent function") is called. This function executes. Inside this function browser sees that there is another nested `g` function. Then browser sees this nested `g` function and understands that it can't remove the lexical environment of the parent function, because this lexical environment is referenced by the nested `g` function. This lexical environment is remained in the memory. Then this nested `g` function is returned and assigned to `g` variable.

Comment: @Bergi Then we give to `g` variable the value of `null`. And then... I don't get what is happening. I don't understand... if lexical environment of parent function is remained in the memory, because its inner `g` function exists and references to its parent function, then why is lexical environment of parent function deleted?

Comment: @Bergi Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Where/when (in what step) exactly are the function `g` and the lexical environment created? And notice that `g = null` does indeed make the function object eligible for garbage collection, that is what causes the lexical environment to be discarded as well. Or if you say that something still holds onto the function object (references it), what would that be?

Comment: @Bergi the function `g` is created when the parent function `f` executes. _Or if you say that something still holds onto the function object (references it), what would that be?_ I thought it's code inside parent function `f` - `function g() { alert(value); }`. It remains after `g = null`.

Comment: @Bergi Or do you want to say that... function `f` executes, returns inner function `g` as a result, assigns that result to variable `g`. **And then browser looks that variable `g` refers to the function `g`, so lexical environment of function `g` stays. And this lexical environment of inner function contains the reference to function `g`, so lexical enviroment of function `f` stays too because inner function `g` contains reference to that function `f`.** Am I right?

Comment: No, there is no lexical environment of `g`, since `g` is never executed. There's only the lexical environment *around* `g`, the one that is created by executing `f()`. And `g`, by being a closure, holds onto that lexical environment (which contains `value: 123` and `g: <function>`). "*I thought it's code inside parent function `f` [that holds onto the function object]*" - no, the code doesn't have references to the functions it created. Notice that each invocation of `f()` returns a *new* function object - consider `const g1 = f(); const g2 = f();`.

Comment: @Bergi  Then what and how exactly holds the reference to the lexical environment of the parent function `f`? Could function `g` contain the reference to the lexical environment of the function `f` without its lexical environment? I mean there are 2 properties in the lexical environment: `Enviroment record` and `[[Environment]]`. **Only `[[Environment]]` can contains the reference to the lexical environment of parent function `f`. How can `[[Environment]]` of function `g` contain the reference to the lexical environment of function `f` if `g` has no lexical environment?**

Comment: I think I'm confused what exactly you mean by "the lexical environment **of** function x". Do you mean the lexical environment created *in* it, or the lexical environment *around* it that it was defined in?

Comment: @Bergi not around, I mean the lexical environment that was created in "function x". Inside. For instance, the lexical enviroment of function `f` contains variable `value` and function `g`

Comment: A function object (closure) directly has a reference to the lexical environment that it was defined in ("the lexical environment of its parent", if you want), as an internal property. Where did you learn about the `[[Environment]]` notation?

Comment: @Bergi In some sources this property sounds differently. [In this article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/a-beginners-guide-to-closures-in-javascript-97d372284dda), it sounds as `reference to the outer environment`. For instance: **"A Lexical Environment has two components: (1) the environment record and (2) a reference to the outer environment."** I meant this

Comment: I think the core sentence of that article you might have missed is "*Please note that when the personLexicalEnvironment is created, the JavaScript engine attaches the personLexicalEnvironment to all of the function definitions inside that lexical environment. So that later on if any of the inner functions are called, the JavaScript engine can set the outer lexical environment to the lexical environment attached to that function definition.*". That's what I mean when I say the function object `g1` references the lexical environment of the `f()` call.